# sql-server: Combing these 2 queries results into 1

Tags: sql-server

I have these 2 queries that create a rank list then I'm selecting a specific row from the result so both queries return 1 value each. How can I join the results so it returns them together. Something with the logic of this:

```
SELECT x.a, y.b FROM (SELECT * from a) as x, (SELECT * FROM b) as y
```

query1

```
declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='Hospital1';

                               WITH cte AS (
                               SELECT 4 score, growth1 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 3 score, growth2 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 2 score, growth3 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 1 score, growth4 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 0 score, growth5 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               ),

                                cte2 AS (
                               SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM cte
                               GROUP BY area
                               HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                   
                               ),

                                cte3 AS (
                               SELECT area, score, 
                               Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) row,
                               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
                               FROM cte2
                               )                                   

                               SELECT top 1 area AS Growth
                               FROM cte3
                               WHERE row = 1
```

query2

```
                               WITH Ecte AS (
                               SELECT 4 score, Efficiency1 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 3 score, Efficiency2 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 2 score, Efficiency3 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 1 score, Efficiency4 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT 0 score, Efficiency5 area FROM Survey
                               WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                               ), Ecte2 AS (
                               SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM Ecte
                               GROUP BY area
                               HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                  

                               ), Ecte3 AS (
                               SELECT area, score, 
                               Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) row,
                               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
                               FROM Ecte2
                               )
                               SELECT TOP 1 area as Efficiency
                               FROM Ecte3
                               WHERE row = 1
```

Comment: Your psuedo-code at the top looks fine as a start.  How will the two queries relate to each other?

Comment: Yea except when I structure my queries that way, I get all sorts of errors. So lets say they are 2 completely unrelated queries. How would one combine the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into `UNION` / `UNION ALL`?  You must have the same # of columns in each return for this to work.

ex:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE2
```

For CTE's do the following:

```
;WITH CTE1 (col1, col2)
AS
(
     SELECT col1, col2
     FROM ...
)
, CTE2 (col1, col2)
AS
(
     SELECT col1, col2
     FROM ....
)

SELECT col1, col2
FROM CTE1
WHERE something = true
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2
FROM CTE2
WHERE something = true
```

NB:  `UNION ALL` will return duplicate rows, `UNION` will eliminate identical rows as if it were `GROUP BY` on every column selected.

Your code would change as follows:

```
declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='Hospital1';

WITH cte AS (
SELECT 4 score, growth1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 score, growth2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 score, growth3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 score, growth4 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, growth5 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
),

cte2 AS (
SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM cte
GROUP BY area
HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                   
),

cte3 AS (
SELECT area, score, 
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) row,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
FROM cte2
),                                 

Ecte AS (
SELECT 4 score, Efficiency1 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 score, Efficiency2 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 score, Efficiency3 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 score, Efficiency4 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 score, Efficiency5 area FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
), Ecte2 AS (
SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM Ecte
GROUP BY area
HAVING area IS NOT NULL                                  

), Ecte3 AS (
SELECT area, score, 
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) row,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
FROM Ecte2
)

SELECT TOP 1 area as Efficiency
FROM Ecte3
WHERE row = 1                              
UNION ALL
SELECT top 1 area AS Growth
FROM cte3
WHERE row = 1
```

If you want the two value side by side, change the final query to this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 T1.area as Efficiency, T2.area AS Growth
FROM Ecte3 T1, cte3 T2
WHERE T1.row = 1 AND T2.row = 1
```

Comment: I have but I get a error under the `with` at the start of the 2nd query. They both return the same num of columns(1). But if I just stick a UNION in between the 2 I get that syntax error.

Comment: If it's cte's then you need to do the select/union after... updating answer.

Comment: Answer updated... you MUST use a CTE as soon as it's created, so just chain all your CTE's with `,` and then do a final `select-union-select`

Comment: Just so I'm clear. Each query returns 1 result/value. I need 1 query that runs both queries so my output then has 2 values. (I need the result of query1 to be next to result of query2). I believe union/unionall will join them into 1 column?

Comment: Your updated answer gives back the correct 2 values except its under 1 column 'Efficiency'. I'm trying to have Efficiency value under Efficiency column, and Growth value under Growth column

Comment: Yes, union will use one column, sorry - that wasn't clear in your question.  Will update.

Comment: Glad to be of some help.